# How can I reconnect a new Postgres server to an old local database?

Tags: postgresql, macos, osx-yosemite, postgresql-9.4

I had to upgrade my OS hard drive and lost my OSX installation and applications. I've recovered almost completely but the very large installation of carefully prepared postGIS tiger files is still waiting to be reconnected.

It is not a pg_dump, although I'm still hunting for some backups. But I remember reading that a Postgres server could simply connect to a well-formed database folder pretty easily.

But I can't get the question formed correctly to find those instructions on google.

Does anyone know how to do this, or how to compose a search phrase that will guide me to the answer?

Comment: postgres like the tag on my question

Comment: If the old Postgres version is the same as the new one, you can simply copy the data directory (of course the new service must be stopped)